# How to get a reference to collectionView header inside scrollViewDidScroll?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am implementing scollViewDidScroll delegate method of the collectionView and I need to get a reference to my header in order to access some outlets inside my header.swift file

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
           let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerID, for: indexPath) as! publicEventsHeader
        header.headerImage.image = UIImage(named: "stadium", in: nil, with: nil)
        header.collectionView.delegate = header
        header.collectionView.dataSource = header
           return header
       }
```

so, how to access the header of this delegate method inside the scrollViewDidScroll method?

Answer (score 1):

Use `visibleSupplementaryViews(ofKind:)` method of the `collectionView` to get all the currently visible *headerViews*.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if let headersViews = (scrollView as? UICollectionView)?.visibleSupplementaryViews(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
        //add your code here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

collectionView header reference in swift

private func getHeaderRefeence() -> UICollectionViewCell {

if let headers = collectionView.visibleSupplementaryViews(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader).first as? UICollectionViewCell{

return headers
}
}